# Install EncFS on Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, encfs

I use EncFS to encrypt my files. So far, I've been using the [installer provided by BoxCryptor](http://blog.boxcryptor.com/encfs-174-installer-for-mac-os-x-available).

It packs EncFS 1.7.4, MacFuse and MacFusion in one installer and works nicely on Mountain Lion. But MacFuse is not actively developed and most people might replace it with [Fuse for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com/) or something similar.

Are there other packaged installers for EncFS? Or do you always compile EncFS from source? If so, is there a tutorial on how to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I moved my comment to an answer to give more visibility to the solution, as this is one of the first results when googling this topic.

`fuse4x` is now merged into `osxfuse`. To continue installing `encfs` from `brew`, try to google something like ["brew encfs osxfuse"](https://www.google.it/search?q=brew+encfs+osxfuse) and if you're feeling lucky, go to [the first result](https://github.com/jollyjinx/encfs.macosx) (which consists in a new formula for `brew`). The procedure can be summarized as:

- install `osxfuse` package from the official site
- `brew install https://raw.github.com/jollyjinx/encfs.macosx/master/encfsmacosxfuse.rb`

EDIT: If you prefer instead to continue using boxcryptor, they released a beta for osx, always using osxfuse. [This is the link to the announce.](https://www.boxcryptor.com/it/node/2142)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'm still not sure about the best way to install encfs. Feels kind of messy, at least there is only osxfuse now, right?

Comment: Well, I can't imagine something more straightforward than this. Install osxfuse, graphically, and then `brew install`. Now you have `encfs` command on terminal. How could it be easier? :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're familiar with the command line, you could try [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Once you install Homebrew, do a

```
brew install encfs
```

to get the latest version (including dependencies), build and install it.

Notes:

1. You may have to force a link through `brew link -f fuse4x` if it throws an error related to linking. Also refer [this page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9557).
2. You would have to run `brew info fuse4x-kext` to get information on installing the `fuse4x` kernel extension. Since we're talking about kernel extensions, have a proper system backup to restore from (in case this makes your system unusable).

Comment: Guess this will work. The EncFS in Homebrew depends on fuse4x. Better than MacFuse because it's still under development. The most active project seems to be FUSE for OS X though (http://osxfuse.github.com/). I think I have to compile myself to use it.